# How to download and install java plugin for firefox 19.0

Tags: firefox, java, plugins

I was in a site (URL : http://www.francocube.com/cyril/step_1.php) and there was animations tht needed a plugin. When I clicked on an animation, Firefox 19.0 showed : "Additional plugins are required to display all the media on this page", so I clicked on "Install missing plugins" and a window "Plugin Finder Service" appeared and said that Firefox 19.0 was now checking for available plugins...
It froze for 10 or 15 minutes, so I assumed that it would not work.
Then, I found a link in the same page who says "Java is not activated in your computer. You have to install Java". I clicked the link but I didn't understand what to do exactly because I am new with Linux.
What can I do ?